# nextjs + mongodb: Mongodb transactions cannot be used in nextjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema, next.js13

I used mongodb's transaction in nextjs, but it never succeeded. I don't know where I didn't write correctly。I am trying to search for various documents, including the official documents of Mongodb, Mongoose, and GitHub, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { ApiError, withApi } from '@/app/api/wrapper';
import { models } from '@/database/mongo';

export const DELETE = withApi(async function (req, { params }) {
    const { menuId } = params;
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            const doc = await models.Menus.findById(menuId).session(session);
            console.log(doc);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error --------------------------');
        throw new ApiError('error');
    } finally {
        console.log('close');
        await session.endSession();
    }
    return null;
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3vlU.png)
I requested three times and I hope the transaction can be executed correctly. I hope he can execute the SQL statement correctly, but he keeps throwing errors.

"next": "13.5.4",
"mongoose": "^8.0.0",
"mongodb": "^5.0.0",

Comment: Please post the error as a text, ant an screenshot